# How to put a paragraph under a header tag in html and center the paragraph under the header

Tags: html, css

```css
.aboutPageStatsHead {
  margin: 3%;
  margin-top: 12%;
  clear: both;
  color: #29aae2;
  font-size: 3.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.aboutPageStatsHeadNext {
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutUsStatsDiv">
  <h3 id="aboutUsStatsDiv1" class="aboutPageStatsHead">20</h3>
  <h3 id="aboutUsStatsDiv2" class="aboutPageStatsHead aboutPageStatsHeadNext">56</h3>
  <h3 id="aboutUsStatsDiv3" class="aboutPageStatsHead aboutPageStatsHeadNext">3</h3>
  <h3 id="aboutUsStatsDiv3" class="aboutPageStatsHead aboutPageStatsHeadNext">3</h3>
</div>
```

I want it look like this but whatever I try I can't move the text under the header to the right left.It can't have a greater margin-right then the header.

[image]

Comment: There's no paragraphs in your HTML (obviously). Please include a [mcve].

Comment: What paragraph, there is none in your code??

Comment: Thats what I am asking how to put a paragraph in a header and center it

Comment: If you don't show us what you tried (with proper HTML & CSS) there is very little we can do.

Comment: Wait I will edit my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap them in a div and center both the p and h3 inside that div

```css
.aboutPageStatsHead {
  margin: 3%;
  margin-top: 12%;
  color: #29aae2;
  display: inline-block;
}

.aboutPageStatsHead h3 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.aboutPageStatsHead p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutUsStatsDiv">

  <div class="aboutPageStatsHead">
    <h3>20</h3>
    <p>Years in Business</p>
  </div>

  <div class="aboutPageStatsHead">
    <h3>56</h3>
    <p>Years in Business</p>
  </div>

  <div class="aboutPageStatsHead">
    <h3>3</h3>
    <p>Years in Business</p>
  </div>

  <div class="aboutPageStatsHead">
    <h3>3</h3>
    <p>Years in Business</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This would keep the paragraph centrally aligned with the header, as they are both centrally aligned relative to the new div.

You then control margins through the new div, rather than off the heading itself.